# how to find next largest number in range from input reference with vba

Tags: vba, excel-formula

Good morning.  I have been asked to find the next largest number in a column of numbers based on a specific number.  for example, the task requires a length of metal to be cut, we have specific sizes of metal say 94", 125", 140" etc... if a customer wants a piece cut 112.5" we would need to select a piece of 125".  Can someone help me with this please.  VBA if possible or excel formula. Thank a million.

Added from comments:

```
Sub FindMe() 
    Dim x As Integer 
    Dim N As Integer 
    N = Range("j2") 
    Rownum = Range("j4", Range("j4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 
    For x = 4 To Rownum 
        If Range("j" & x) > N Then 
             Cells("I2") = Cells("J" & x) 
        End If 
        Exit Sub 
    Next x 
End Sub
```

Comment: look into index - match formula.  it will do what you ask.

Comment: Sub FindMe()

Dim x As Integer
Dim N As Integer
N = Range("j2")

Rownum = Range("j4", Range("j4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For x = 4 To Rownum
    If Range("j" & x) > N Then
     Cells("I2") = Cells("J" & x)
   End If
        Exit Sub
   Next x

End Sub
 Here is what I have written.

Comment: The formula I hinted at and Macro Man did would work.  For what you are asking that is the cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your sizes are in Column A and the customer requested size is in B1:

1. Sort all of your values in Column A so that they are descending (largest to smallest)
2. Enter this formula in C1

   `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(B1,A:A,-1))`

---

VBA alternative (as requested)

Assuming there is header in A1:

```
Sub MacroMan()

Dim vals, size, result
'// assign range values to array
vals = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).value

'// bubble sort array to descending values
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
         For j = i + 1 To UBound(vals)
             If vals(i, 1) < vals(j, 1) Then
                 SrtTemp = vals(j, 1)
                 vals(j, 1) = vals(i, 1)
                 vals(i, 1) = SrtTemp
             End If
         Next j
     Next i
'// required size
size = Range("C1").value

'// find required size in array
result = WorksheetFunction.Match(size, vals, -1)

'// show result
MsgBox "Size required: " & vals(result, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Works beautifully.  I have to stop over thinking on this stuff!!!!!!!!   Any suggestion on the VBA route?

Comment: See edit - don't forget to mark as answer if it helped.

Comment: Thank you. Greatly appreciated.  I understand the sorting of the array to descending, but what is the purpose of the "SrtTemp"?

Comment: I knocked a line out by accident with my last edit - I've put it back in now `SrtTemp` is just a variant to hold a temporary value for the sort, it should make sense now. (Using my phone which usually results in errors like this!)